# How do I retrieve a file from the gitlab repository branch using Java?

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

This is my GitLab structure

- Project X

  - Repository J

    - Branches 1

      - File A
      - File B
    - Branches 2

      - File C
      - File D

I want to retrieve File A from Branches 1 Repository J using Java Code. Is there a way on how to do it? I've been looking for this method but can't find it.

Comment: Ref : https://github-api.kohsuke.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a file from a repository using the [Repository Files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository):

```sh
GITLAB="gitlab.example.com"
PROJECT_ID=13083
FILE_PATH="/path/to/filename.java"
BRANCH_NAME="main"

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://${GITLAB}/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/repository/files/${FILE_PATH}?ref=${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

Most of this is pretty clear, but you can get the Project ID from the Projects API response, or from the Project page in Gitlab right under the project name. The File Path should be the path to the file from the root of your project. The `ref` parameter can be either a branch name, tag name, or a commit sha.

Comment: Any idea on how this works with Git LFS files? If I follow your answer I get back a pointer, instead of the actual LFS file.

Comment: The docs don't specify any differences with LFS, so I can't say without seeing details specific to your use case. Would you mind posting the response (without any sensitive info) in a new question?

Comment: Sure, I've posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69619938/1256347), thanks for your time in advance if you can have a look.