# How can I programmatically retrieve a file from Gitlab LFS?

Tags: curl, gitlab

#### Question

How can I programmatically download a file from Gitlab when it requires authentication?

#### Context

I want to retrieve LFS files from Gitlab programmatically. The [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api) does not provide a proper endpoint unfortunately.

When I for example run the following `curl` command:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXX' 'https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/4992/repository/files/folder%2Ffilename%2Ebz2?ref=tag-v0.1.0'
```

I get back a small (138 bytes) JSON pointer file, while in reality the file is approximately 4 MB.

#### What I've tried

##### Gitlab API: [get file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository)

As shown above, I've tried using the API, but I only get back a pointer file, not the actual object stored in the LFS system.

##### Gitlab API: [get raw file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository)

If I use the get raw file method:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXX' 'https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/4992/repository/files/folder%2Ffilename%2Ebz2/raw?ref=tag-v0.1.0'
```

I get the pointer again, but this time as plain text.

##### Use webapp endpoint

I found [two](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/download-lfs-file-content-not-pointer-with-api/15504) forum [posts](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/api-download-lfs-file/6297/2) about the same issue. In both posts the use of the webapp URL is suggested instead of the API endpoint.

By webapp URL I assume they mean the URL of the button that I click on the Gitlab webpage to download the file.
That URL looks like this:

```
https://gitlab.company.com/group_name/project_name/-/raw/tag-v0.1.0/folder/filename.bz2
```

But, if I try that URL with the private token in `curl`:

```
curl --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXX' https://gitlab.company.com/group_name/project_name/-/raw/tag-v0.1.0/folder/filename.bz2
```

I get:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://gitlab.company.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Comment: maybe https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27892#note_395085312 is useful for you - i cant evaluate, but i think it might help here

Comment: Thanks, I just found that as well, currently going through the steps of the non-ssh version, but I get a `403` error when I get to the LFS_OBJECT_ACTION_DOWNLOAD step. Now trying the SSH option.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using the [Get Raw File API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository)? It should be the equivalent of hitting the 'raw' button in the UI, though it does not saw anything specifically about LFS

Comment: That's the API I was referring to in the "Gitlab API: get raw file" subsection.  The result unfortunately is still a small pointer file, unless I am doing the API call wrong?